# Sampling from a distribution with a margin of error

Tags: math, random, statistics, distribution

The following code samples a weighted random distribution as part of a simulation representing the options 100k individuals may take (eg: voting etc).

There are two possible options with weights of 30% and 70% respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
   int option0 = 30; //30%
   int option1 = 70; //30%

   std::vector<int> option({0,0});

   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 gen(rd());
   std::discrete_distribution<> d({option0,option1});

   for (int n=0; n < 100000; ++n)
   {
      ++option[d(gen)];
   }

   std::cout << "Option 0: " << option[0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Option 1: " << option[1] << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

If the above percentages (weights) were derived by taking a survey of a population using sampling and the [margin of error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margin_of_error) was determined to be ***5%***.

How would one go about modifying the above simulation to take into account *(aka incorporate)* the 5% margin of error?

Answer (score 0):

Because you know exactly the margin of error, you can modify the weights with
a randomly generated double (between -5.0 and 5.0) and then run your proposed simulation.

This function will simulate the desired margin of error :

```
void
simulating_margin_of_error(std::mt19937 gen, double marginOfError,
                           int* option0, int* option1)
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>
        distribution(-marginOfError,marginOfError);
    double number = distribution(gen);

    *option0 += (int) number;
    *option1 += - (int) number;
}
```

And you can include it here :

```
[...]
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
simulating_margin_of_error(gen, 5.0, &option0, &option1);
std::discrete_distribution<> d({option0, option1});
[...]
```